# Windows Firewall Configuration for Blocking Internet Access

Tags: proxy, blocking, windows-firewall

I have a PC and a laptop. I would like to make my PC act as server and my laptop as a client. I want to implement a freeware HTTP proxy (`freeproxy` 4.10) on my PC so that it can filter certain web pages.

The thing is, the proxy I just downloaded will only work if the client (my laptop) connects to the port that is set. If the user didn't connect to the port that is set by that freeproxy, they can surf like usual without being blocked.

I heard Windows Firewall can block internet access by blocking some port and letting some ports communicate with internet. I just wonder how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simple route, and the one most used is to force the connection to go through the proxy/firewall by using two network cards in your PC. Have the laptop connect to one, and have the other connect to the internet - then just configure the proxy to look at every request coming in from the network the laptop is on. This could be a wireless network if required.

Alternatively, just configure your laptop to always use a proxy, and set the proxy details to include IP and port required. This will work, but could be changed by a user on the laptop if they have the required permissions.

> Tools - Internet Options - Connections
>   - LAN settings - Proxy Server

For this functionality you don't need to use the Windows Firewall at all.

Comment: +1 Firewall isn't a good idea. It will block access, but it won't route you to the correct port.

Comment: thanks for the answer,
Yes, I am aware that i just have to configure from Internet Options, the thing is I don't want anyone using my laptop can simply change my configuration. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can lock down those settings so only an admin can change them, then give the users normal user accounts. Of course a determined attacker with access to your laptop can do anything, but this will at least add protection against an average user.